# Extract & Collection of data for Real estate data Company

Tags: database, artificial-intelligence, extract, data-analysis

I am in a real estate company(Gurgaon,India) as a data analyst ,they want me to extract data from sites that can be useful, please let me know how can i extract good data from websites without paying for it.
is there any website where we can find data, please let me know
Thank you

I am looking for a source for data extraction or guidance to do that